# htaccess redirect 2 wordpress installations

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

tried almost anything but i cannot get it to work

I have wordpress installation on my root folder and another installation on a subdirectory.
I have been trying to use mod_rewrite to divert all traffic coming to a sub domain to the sub directory where the other installation is.

basically i want to divert traffic coming from ads.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/ads (without redirecting and changing the url)
I have been using this rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ads/$1 [L]
```

it is working fine except that calling ads.mydomain.com/wp-admin redirects me to the main domain (www.mydomain.com/wp-admin) ...
what is wrong here ?

Comment: You never exclude `ads.` subdomain from the conditions, so why wouldn't it redirect?

Comment: well that is my question :-) i obviously don't know

Comment: Ahhhh now I understand the question. Is the `/ads` URL working when you call it directly?

Comment: it redirects me to ads.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ads.domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.ads.domainname.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ads
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

on httpd.conf